# buildozer build the apk but don't work on android

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, smartphone, kivymd

Hello i have build the apk with the command:

buildozer android debug deploy run logcat:

```
03-25 22:34:57.822 29612 30258 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
03-25 22:34:57.824 29612 30258 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
03-25 22:34:57.828 29612 30258 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2.dev0, git-Unknown, 2021-01-17 (installed at "./kivymd/__init__.pyc")
03-25 22:34:57.846 29612 30258 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
03-25 22:34:58.090  2824 30154 I display : [PrimaryDisplay] [DYNAMIC_RECOMP] HWC_2_GLES by low FPS(0)
03-25 22:34:58.532 29612 30258 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
03-25 22:34:59.162 29612 30258 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-25 22:34:59.163 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 702, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.164 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
03-25 22:34:59.165 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
03-25 22:34:59.165 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 555, in kivy.properties.Property.set
03-25 22:34:59.166 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1264, in kivy.properties.BoundedNumericProperty.check
03-25 22:34:59.167 29612 30258 I python  :  TypeError: Cannot convert kivy.properties.NumericPropertyStorage to kivy.properties.BoundedNumericPropertyStorage
03-25 22:34:59.167 29612 30258 I python  :  
03-25 22:34:59.168 29612 30258 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
03-25 22:34:59.168 29612 30258 I python  :  
03-25 22:34:59.169 29612 30258 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-25 22:34:59.169 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 182, in <module>
03-25 22:34:59.170 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/app.py", line 954, in run
03-25 22:34:59.171 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
03-25 22:34:59.171 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 85, in build
03-25 22:34:59.172 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 307, in load_file
03-25 22:34:59.173 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 409, in load_string
03-25 22:34:59.174 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.175 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
03-25 22:34:59.175 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 542, in apply
03-25 22:34:59.176 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.177 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.178 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
03-25 22:34:59.179 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 542, in apply
03-25 22:34:59.179 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 711, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.180 29612 30258 I python  :  kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 15:
03-25 22:34:59.181 29612 30258 I python  :  ...
03-25 22:34:59.181 29612 30258 I python  :       13:    size_hint: None, None
03-25 22:34:59.181 29612 30258 I python  :       14:    height: dp(20) + root.lbl_txt.texture_size[1]
03-25 22:34:59.182 29612 30258 I python  :  >>   15:    width: lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + dp(24)
03-25 22:34:59.182 29612 30258 I python  :       16:
03-25 22:34:59.182 29612 30258 I python  :       17:    MDLabel:
03-25 22:34:59.183 29612 30258 I python  :  ...
03-25 22:34:59.183 29612 30258 I python  :  TypeError: Cannot convert kivy.properties.NumericPropertyStorage to kivy.properties.BoundedNumericPropertyStorage
03-25 22:34:59.183 29612 30258 I python  :    File "/home/lauri/Py/beach_order/client/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/order/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 702, in _apply_rule
03-25 22:34:59.184 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
03-25 22:34:59.184 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
03-25 22:34:59.184 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 555, in kivy.properties.Property.set
03-25 22:34:59.184 29612 30258 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1264, in kivy.properties.BoundedNumericProperty.check
03-25 22:34:59.185 29612 30258 I python  :  
03-25 22:34:59.185 29612 30258 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

please help me!! i don't understand the problem.
I have build the apk and run, but crash at start.
yesterday the application was working, after I changed the spec file and got this error. I rewrote the spec file as in origin but the error always remains

the only different is that i was update ubuntu 20.04 lts, app and kernel.

i try to delete .buildozer folder and .spec file

after:

buildozer init and
adding the requirements

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = android,python3==3.8.5,kivy==master,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,pygments,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,jnius,pyjnius,plyer,pillow,xclip,xsel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in KivyMD and/or your own code, revealed by a recent change in Kivy master. Use the latest Kivy release, or wait for it to be fixed in Kivy MD.

See https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7398 for details.

Answer (score 1):

`width: root.lbl_txt.texture_size[0] + dp(24)` ?

Comment: The string Is in the kivy.lang.builder, not in my script

Comment: Try to deploy a HelloWorld App to be sure that it is coming from buildozer.
If the Hello World crash -> change buildozer version until this is working.
If the Hello World works, you should check your code / libraries / path_needed and implement little by little.